# Is there a way to force the matplotlib OO interface?

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are multiple ways to use the matplotlib library, however, I always found, as a teacher, the state-driven `pyplot` interface kind of confusing because of the auto-magic things happening in the background:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]) # Lots of magic here
plt.title("Simple plot")       # Some magic here... (not obvious where will be the title)
plt.savefig("plot.pdf")        # ...and there
```

I wish I could force my students/colleagues to use the OO interface along a much more restricted set of higher functions, typically

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()       # Cleaner (more pythonic, even though not fully OO...)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9])  # plot is indeed a method of Axes
ax.set_title("Simple plot")    # title is indeed associated to axes
fig.savefig("plot.pdf")        # savefig is indeed a methode of Figures
```

Is there an easy way to do so? (e.g. disable `plt.plot`, etc.)

Comment: Upvoted as an interesting technical question -- although with dubious social outcomes.

Comment: Maybe assign `plt.plot = lambda *_: print("Please call ax.plot() instead of 'plt.plot'")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not fully OO" for `plt.subplots`?

Comment: Some could argue that a fully OO solution would be to create 1st the canva, add a figure, etc. But that's not an issue here.